# When the URL contains a mail yahoo address, I got 301 http code

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

In parts of my program, I need to send email address via query string parameters (regardless of whether this is good or not) like this:

```
http://www.example.com/index.phtml?A=B&email=abc@yahoo.com&C=D
```

This URL returns 301 http code and redirect me to the https://us.yahoo.com ! 
It is interesting that this problem does not exist for other email address like gmail !
This is my index.phtml code:

```
<?
    echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

Now the question is: What happened??

I am using 'PHP version 5' and 'Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)' in 'Cent OS' server.
In addition, rewrite engine is off (in .htaccess file) and 'mod_rewrite.c' is disabled too.

appreciate any help.

Comment: review/paste your php code or at least paste your rewriting configuration, otherwise are just expecting people to guess?

Comment: Check your other rules and php code for this 301

Comment: thanks for your reply; this code on another server works fine. Which rules should I check?

Comment: Your URL is not valid. The parameter names and values need to be URLEncoded. `@` is not a legal character.

Comment: Oh thanks! But it is not an ENCODED URL, it is only A SIMPLE EXAMPLE ! it is clear that when send it to the server, it will be encoded! In addition, I had a lot of servers with no error, except this. Anyway, I have solved this problem by query string elimination. Thank you for your late reply dear @EJP !